# If you had two automail arms, could you still use alchemy?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

So, say someone in the *Fullmetal Alchemist* world lost both of their arms.

Could they still preform alchemy with their automail arms? Is there a way to adjust the automail so you can use alchemy?

Comment: The automail doesn't obstruct someone from using alchemy, as far as I understand the mechanism in FMA. Putting aside the cases of people who have committed the taboo, people perform transmutation by transmutation circles. As long as they can draw a circle, I guess they can perform alchemy.

Comment: Oh Okay thank you! Thats what I thought, just wanted to make sure with more fans of FMA.

Comment: Isn't Al just a metal suit of armor? And he was able to use alchemy, so I don't see why someone with two automail can't.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes, they could... sort of.**

As Scar mentions in episode 5, the only requirement is for the person to produce a circle. Izumi states that this is what lets the transmutation energy flow (or "power", depending on your sub/dub). Most alchemists draw transmutation circles, but those who have seen beyond the Gate of Truth instead create their own circle with their body.

[image: "So you transmute by placing your hands together and forming a circle."]

> **Izumi:** A basis of a transmutation circle is the power of the circle. The circle displays the circulation of power, and by sketching the construction symbol in it, it becomes possible to activate its power. This is also a circulation of power. It's best to experience it for yourself. Now... Review it until lunch is ready!
>
> **Alphonse:** Okay, so... The circle displays the circulation of power, and by sketching the construction symbol in it, it becomes possible to activate its power. But you were transmuting by just slapping your palms together, weren't you, Master? Do you not need to sketch the construction symbols?
>
> **Izumi:** I am like a construction symbol.

[image: "I am like a construction symbol."]

Ed is able to do his through clapping his regular hand with his metal hand (or gloved hand) because the flesh pushing against the metal creates a circular seal for the energy flow.

Al is able to do this because both his "hands" are gloved, so the fabric can compress together enough to create the same kind of circular seal as above.

So, **as long as the two metal arms could compress together in a circular pattern**, the user could create the required energy flow, and would be able to use alchemy (as long as they had been through the Gate).